# File Sorting - Item Types - Java

Tags: java, swing

Fairly new to Java Programming, and have recently built an app that takes input from the user of the title of a Movie, Book or Song (From Radio Buttons) and prints it to a text file like this:

```
Movie Title: The Imitation Game Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:52:39 
Music Title: Fly For Your Life  Artist: Gunship  Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:52:51 
Book Title: Alan Turing: The Enigma Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:53:05M
Music Title: Adagio For Tron Artist: Daft Punk   Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:54:06
Music Title: Bad Wings Artist: The Glitch Mob   Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:54:13
Movie Title: Rear Window Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:54:28
```

So, what I'm asking is how do I sort by Movies, Music or Books in the Text File?

I want to be able to, whenever the program ends (I'm using JFrame and JPanel for the UI) it sorts the Movies, then the Music, then the Books into a list.

I'd like to not only have the actual answer a sample of code but also a tutorial on what it does and how it works.

Comment: I have some experience with this, nothing professional or extensive. Would it be easier to just save them to separate files?

Comment: Start with [Trail: Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) and [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), look for the `sort` methods and [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can create 3 different classes, one for movies, one for books and one for songs.

```
public class Movies throws Exception {
String title;
Date date;
public Movie(String title, Date date){ 
this.title = title;
this.date = date;
}

public class Book throws Exception {
String title;
String author;
Date date;
public Book(String title,String author, Date date){ //constructor of Book
this.title = title;
this.author = author;
this.date = date;
}
```

And for the song the same as the book.

When you are in real-time executing the app, you can print things as they are comming (just like in your example), but at the same time, register them in linkedLists or Arrays of it's own (Movie[] movs , Book bok[] etc):

```
Movie mov[] = new Movie[2000];
int n = 0;
//the app begins
System.out.println(INFOMovie) //this is the method you use to print the  information of a movie(supposed thing)
mov[n] = INFOMovie.title ,INFOMovie.date);
//and so on
```

and when the app finishes, before the exit, make a sort method that first reads all the movies, then the books, and then the songs, and make them appear on the JPanel in the order you want. Something like this:
    int n=0;

```
while(n!= mov.length){
System.out.println(mov[n].toString); //the toString method is a method you can have in your classes where you make a string with all the info you want to have about that class (this time, the movie one).
}
n=0;
while(n!=bok.length){
System.out.println(mov[n].toString);
}
```

and so on.

I think I've understood the problem you have, if I don't , make me know it I'll change my answer so it can fit your question. Also, If you don't know any part of my answer, say it, and I'll explain it better.

Also, what MadProgrammer did is pretty good. If you have any question ask it.

Answer (score 2):

> So, what I'm asking is how do I sort by Movies, Music or Books in the Text File?

Essentially, you don't.  You load the values into memory, sort them there and save them back to the file.

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(25);
values.add("Movie Title: The Imitation Game Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:52:39");
values.add("Music Title: Fly For Your Life  Artist: Gunship  Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:52:51)");
values.add("Book Title: Alan Turing: The Enigma Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:53:05M");
values.add("Music Title: Adagio For Tron Artist: Daft Punk   Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:54:06");
values.add("Music Title: Bad Wings Artist: The Glitch Mob   Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:54:13");
values.add("Movie Title: Rear Window Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:54:28");    

Collections.sort(values, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        String t1 = o1.substring(0, o1.indexOf(" ")).trim();
        String t2 = o2.substring(0, o2.indexOf(" ")).trim();
        return t1.compareTo(t2);
    }
});

for (String value : values) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Which outputs...

```
Book Title: Alan Turing: The Enigma Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:53:05M
Movie Title: The Imitation Game Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:52:39
Movie Title: Rear Window Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:54:28
Music Title: Fly For Your Life  Artist: Gunship  Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:52:51)
Music Title: Adagio For Tron Artist: Daft Punk   Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:54:06
Music Title: Bad Wings Artist: The Glitch Mob   Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:54:13
```

This is simply using the "natural" order of the `String`s to sort the elements by, if you want something more complicated, you'd have to write the rules for it within the `compare` method of the `Comparator`

Take a look at [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), look for the `sort` methods and [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for more details

## You could...

Keep each type within it's own `List` and save them either sequentially or within there own file...

## You could...

Use a `Map` of some kind to keep like items grouped together...

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapItems = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Music", new ArrayList<String>(25));

map.get("Music").add("The Imitation Game Date & Time: 01/15/2015 08:52:39");
//...
```

Take a look at [Trail: Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details.

## You could...

Bite the bullet and try your hand at using a database of some kind, there are a number of simple, single user, databases available, [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) for example, which is a pure Java database.  Have a look at [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) for more details...

Regardless, I would encourage you to design a base class or interface which maintain the basic information (title and timestamp from the looks of it), then create specialty classes, like `Music`/`Book`/`Movie` which extended from it.  This will make the management easier in the long run, as the information is maintained within the concept of it's own container type (and allows for specialisation of each type)